# Hibernate in Netbeans Application

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, netbeans

How do I configure hibernate in a NetBeans application?

Answer (score 2):

- [Using Hibernate in a Web Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html)
- [Using NetBeans for Building Hibernate Based Web Applications](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HibernateAndWebApp)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html).  Google is pretty good at answering these types of questions.